# Express returns empty Array, but array is fine

Tags: arrays, rest, express, mongoose

All things are going right, when I try to log array it writes everything true but when I try to return as response, it goes empty to front-end. I'm not sure why this is happening, the normal messages array works fine. I don't know why.

```
console.log('messageye girdi');

MessageModel.find({
    receiver: req.body.uuid,
    read: false
  }).then((Messages) => {
      function removeDups(names) {
        let unique = {};
        names.forEach(function(i) {
          if (!unique[i]) {
            unique[i] = true;
          }
        });

        return Object.keys(unique);
      }

      let Users = [];

      Messages.forEach(Message => {
        Users.push(Message.sender);
      })

      const nonduplicate = removeDups(Users);

      console.log(nonduplicate);

      const MessageUsers = [];

      var bu = 0;

      nonduplicate.forEach(User => {
        UserModel.findOne({
          uuid: User
        }).then((UserData) => {
          console.log(UserData.username);

          MessageUsers.push(UserData.username);

          console.log(MessageUsers);
        })

        bu++;

        if (bu = nonduplicate.length) {
          console.log("bu mu acaba " + JSON.stringify(MessageUsers));

          let ArrayVer = Object.assign({}, MessageUsers);

          return res.send({
            success: true,
            users: MessageUsers
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: Hi, this is a non running snippet with several loggings and arrays, so you need to be more specific: which *console.log* and which *array*?

Comment: The last returning one, MessageUsers is fine but returning empty to FE.